# Confused for the "which" in R

Tags: r

I am one green hand and confused for following coding when using "which"

```
> s
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4
> s[which(s$a>1)][,]
[1] 3 4
> #what I want in fact is to get the dataframe if value a>1 
> s[which(s$a>=1)][,]
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4
> #no difference for >1 or >=1
> s[which(s$a%in%c(2))][,]
[1] 3 4
> #this way works
> s[which(s$a%in%c(1,2))][,]
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4
> str(s)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2
 $ b: num  3 4
```

Comment: Thanks if you can help.

Comment: There is a distinct difference between `s[which(s$a>1)]` and `s[which(s$a>1),]`. I suggest you read [`?Extract`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/Extract).

Comment: Thanks, let me read this...

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you are expecting?

Comment: I think I omit the comma in codding, in fact what I want is to extract the dataframe  based on judging the a value...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief explanation:
If you do this you get the value 2(an index)

```
which(df$a>1)
[1] 2
```

Now depending on the nature of subsetting used, you either get rows or columns. 
This returns a column(column 2).

```
df[which(df$a>1)]
  b
1 3
2 4
```

This returns the right value(I assume it is what you want)

```
df[which(df$a>1),]
  a b
2 2 4
```

**NOTE::**

```
df<-read.table(text="a b
 1 3
 2 4",header=T)
```